# setTitle() "sometimes" doesn't work. Google Form

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

Purpose:

I want to add a hundred items to Google Form from Google Spreadsheet.

Problem:

All the items and choices are safely added to the form but not "some" titles.

1. When I excute the code, 70% of the titles are added but 30% of the titles fail.
2. That 30% of failed titles varies on every execution. Even though the title adding was successful this time, it might fails next time. It's so random for me.
3. There is no error code.

Hypothesis:

I am assuming that getTitles is unstable. Google Server fails sometimes. So that there is no way to control the stability. Am I wrong?

```js
function testLoop() {
  //* Definition of Form & Sheet. *//
  const testform4 = FormApp.openById('1gp3M8wsXHNdbEBstaT5B86XmiMoSM43aSwdi8zSC5qU');
  const testsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1rWNVZ8nzdXdCxFtGHe2_NxzkXyxurazfjU8pWYPhmKQ')
    .getSheetByName('testsheet1');
  
  // Add Items
  for (let i = 3; i < 104; i++) {
    //* Sheet to Form *//   // REFACTOR: 
    // Get the item type.
    let itemType = testsheet.getRange(i, 2).getValue();

    //* Add items *//
    // Add section. //
    if (itemType == "addPageBreakItem") {
      // Set an Item-Object.
      let itemObject = testform4.addPageBreakItem();
      // Get the Title from Sheet.
      let itemTitle = testsheet.getRange(i, 1).getValue();
      // Set the title.
      // @ts-ignore
      itemObject.setTitle(itemTitle);
      console.log('- The item, "' + itemTitle + '": ' + itemType +  ',  is added.')
    }
    // Add description.
    else if (itemType == "addSectionHeaderItem") {
      // Set an Item-Object.
      let itemObject = testform4.addSectionHeaderItem();
      // Get the Title from Sheet.
      let itemTitle = testsheet.getRange(i, 1).getValue();
      //FIX: It fales to get the value.

      // Set the title.
      // @ts-ignore
      itemObject.setTitle(itemTitle);
      console.log('- The item, "' + itemTitle + '": ' + itemType +  ',  is added.')
    }
    // Add short-answer.
    else if (itemType == "addTextItem") {
      // Set an Item-Object.
      let itemObject = testform4.addTextItem();
      // Get the Title from Sheet.
      let itemTitle = testsheet.getRange(i, 1).getValue();
      // Set the title.
      // @ts-ignore
      itemObject.setTitle(itemTitle);
      // require number
      // Check if it requires number.
      const requireNumberCheck = testsheet.getRange(i, 3).getValue();
      if (requireNumberCheck == 1) {
        let textValidation = FormApp
          .createTextValidation()
          .requireNumber()
          .setHelpText('Please input the number')
          .build();
        itemObject.setValidation(textValidation);
        console.log("requireNumber is TRUE.");
      }
      console.log('- The item, "' + itemTitle + '": ' + itemType +  ',  is added.')
    }
    // Add multiple choice. 
    else if (itemType == "addMultipleChoiceItem") {
      // Set an Item-Object.
      // @ts-ignore
      let itemObject = testform4.addMultipleChoiceItem();
      // Get the Title from Sheet.
      let itemTitle = testsheet.getRange(i, 1).getValue();
      // Set the title.
      // @ts-ignore
      itemObject.setTitle(itemTitle);
      // Add choices. // MEMO: Inside square brackets loop didn't work.
      itemObject.setChoices([
        // @ts-ignore
        itemObject.createChoice(testsheet.getRange(i, 5).getValue()),
        // @ts-ignore
        itemObject.createChoice(testsheet.getRange(i, 6).getValue()),
        // @ts-ignore
        itemObject.createChoice(testsheet.getRange(i, 7).getValue()),
        // @ts-ignore
        itemObject.createChoice(testsheet.getRange(i, 8).getValue()),
        // @ts-ignore
        itemObject.createChoice(testsheet.getRange(i, 9).getValue()),
        // @ts-ignore
        itemObject.createChoice(testsheet.getRange(i, 10).getValue()),
        // @ts-ignore
        itemObject.createChoice(testsheet.getRange(i, 11).getValue())]);
      // Add other option if the other option is true.
      if (testsheet.getRange(i, 11).getValue() == 4) {
        itemObject.showOtherOption(true);
        console.log('Other-Option is added.');
      }
      console.log('- The item, "' + itemTitle + '": ' + itemType +  ',  is added.')
    }
    // Add checkbox. 
    else if (itemType == "addCheckboxItem") {
      // Set an Item-Object.
      let itemObject = testform4.addCheckboxItem();
      // Get the Title from Sheet.
      let itemTitle = testsheet.getRange(i, 1).getValue();
      // Set the title.
      // @ts-ignore
      itemObject.setTitle(itemTitle);
      // Add choices. // MEMO: Inside square brackets loop didn't work.
      itemObject.setChoices([
        // @ts-ignore
        itemObject.createChoice(testsheet.getRange(i, 5).getValue()),
        // @ts-ignore
        itemObject.createChoice(testsheet.getRange(i, 6).getValue()),
        // @ts-ignore
        itemObject.createChoice(testsheet.getRange(i, 7).getValue()),
        // @ts-ignore
        itemObject.createChoice(testsheet.getRange(i, 8).getValue()),
        // @ts-ignore
        itemObject.createChoice(testsheet.getRange(i, 9).getValue()),
        // @ts-ignore
        itemObject.createChoice(testsheet.getRange(i, 10).getValue()),
        // @ts-ignore
        itemObject.createChoice(testsheet.getRange(i, 11).getValue())]);
      // Add other option if the other option is true.
      if (testsheet.getRange(i, 11).getValue() == 4) {
        itemObject.showOtherOption(true);
        console.log('Other-Option is added.');
      }
      console.log('- The item, "' + itemTitle + '": ' + itemType +  ',  is added.')
    }
    // Add date.
    else {
      // Set an Item-Object.
      let itemObject = testform4.addDateItem();
      // Get the Title from Sheet.
      let itemTitle = testsheet.getRange(i, 1).getValue();
      // Set the title.
      // @ts-ignore
      itemObject.setTitle(itemTitle);
      console.log('- The item, "' + itemTitle + '": ' + itemType +  ',  is added.')
    }
  }
  console.log("All the items are added.");
}
```

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FNoqg.png)

Comment: Are you sure you do not have empty values in column 1 in testsheet? Can you share a sample of your sheet and form for troubleshooting?

Comment: Hello, Ziganotschka. Thank you for your comment.

This is the screenshot of my testSheet.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fjifo5zDjQ3vNOx9oXmIsaq8MBRXI8ud/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Hi, I guess the problem is solved. I just waited overnight, refresh the browser, then, all the titles are added. I don't know why. It worked this time but it failed sometimes in the past. Thank you anyway. I'll let you know if this happens again.